# Doing overlays in Plone 4?

Tags: plone

For a Plone 4 app I need to write a viewlet with a some small search form.
On form submission the result should be presented in an overlay.

Is there some documentation or example code on using overlays in Plone 4?

Comment: http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/client-side-functionality-javascript/popup-overlays-forms

Comment: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.jquerytools

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The built-in overlays in Plone 4 are provided via the [plone.app.jquerytools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.jquerytools) package.

You can look at [popupforms.js](http://svn.plone.org/svn/plone/Products.CMFPlone/trunk/Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_ecmascript/popupforms.js) from Plone itself as an example of how to use it.